# Show custom name in App-To-Phone Calls in Sinch

Tags: android, phone-call, sinch

I'm developing an Android application that allows users to make app to phone calls and it is working pretty fine at the moment but, I want to show a custom name when the remote user receive the call. Now, the phone receiving the call is showing an unknown caller name.

My question is if there is a way to achieve this or it's impossible to show what i want.

Comment: I think that it is up to your call gateway's operator if they support it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways do do this:

1. User callUserWithHeaders and add a friedly name as a header
2. Look up the username in your backend when you recieve the call and display the friendly name

Comment: I want to make AppToPhone calls, and callUserWithHeaders makes an AppToApp call if i'm not wrong.
It's possible to achieve the same result with AppToPhone calls?

Comment: @alcaamado have you solve your problem to set user id ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, to show a custom name when users receive a call, is necessary  to buy first a phone number from Sinch an use it when making calls. Then, in your app, you need to save that number as a contact with the name you desire and it will show up when calls are received.

Comment: hi @alcaamado  can you be please more specific?